# Boole's rule for N intervals (C)

Tags: c++, c, math, floating-point-precision, integral

I am attempting to implement Boole's rule over n intervals using this formula [image: boole's rule]
[image: x=]

So far I have developed this code:

```
//f = function on the range [a,b] n = number of intervals
long double booles(long double (*f) (long double), 
                double a, double b, int n) 
{
  long double sum=7*f(a); //because the starting value is not doubled 
  long double h = (b - a)/(n-1); //width of each interval
  int mod;
  int i =1;
  while (i<n-1)
    {
      mod = i%4;
      if (mod==0)
        sum+=14*f(a+i*h);
      else if (mod==1)
        sum+=32*f(a+i*h);
      else if (mod==2)
        sum+=12*f(a+i*h);
      else
        sum+=32*f(a+i*h);
      ++i;
    }
  return 2* h/45 * sum;
}
```

This will run and give a decent answer but it not within the rules for Bool's error which states that the error is [image: error].
I fixed the problem with doubling the first term but I am not sure how to fix the possible doubling near the end of the loop. Also, the error is relatively large enough that I don't think that my only problem is the last four terms.

Comment: finished editing my answer at the end is the code, you have error in your code the coefficients of yours does not match the formula ... mod==0 case should be `7.0*` not `14.0*` ... btw this should be tag as C++ you are using `++i;`

Comment: @Spektre Unfortunilty this would only be correct if I was only looping through the calculations once. I need the end of one iteration of bools rule to overlap with the start of the next iteration. Here is Simpson's 3/8 rule to demonstrate the need for overlap (when not being looped through)![1]  (http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/3/0/0/300d2d0c06dc4de8779a9aacc77b4787.png)
(when being looped through)
!(2)[http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/5/c/75cf52931aefa878804dce67041dcffd.png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **long double**

   **Wiki says:** extended precision floating-point type. Actual properties unspecified. Unlike types float and double, it can be either 80-bit floating point format, the non-IEEE "double-double" or IEEE 754 quadruple-precision floating-point format if a higher precision format is provided, otherwise it is the same as double. See the article on long double for details.

   - so it is hard to say what datatype you actually use (I prefer to use doubles)
2. **constants**

   you are mixing integer and floating numbers together so the compiler has to decide what to use. Rewrite all floating numbers as `45` to `45.0` to be sure it is done correctly or `a+i*h` ... the `i` is int and `h` is double ...
3. **integration**

   do not know the magnitude of the sum and range of your values but to improve floating precision you should **avoid adding big and small values together** because if the exponents are too different you loose too much of relevant mantissa bits.

   So do the sum in two variables something like this (in C++):

   ```
   double suml=0.0,sumh=0.0,summ=1000.0;
   for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    suml+=...; // here goes the formula
    if (fabs(suml)>summ) { sumh+=suml; suml=0; }
    } sumh+=suml; suml=0;
   // here the result is in sumh
   ```

   - `summ` is max magnitude of suml. It should be in relatively safe range in comparison to your sum iteration value for example `100-10000` times bigger then average value.
   - `suml` is the low magnitudes sum variable
   - `sumh` is the big magnitudes sum variable

   if the range of your summed values is really big then you can add another if

   ```
   if (fabs(value)>summ) sumh+=value; else suml+=value;
   ```

   if it is even much bigger then you can sum into any count of variables in the same manner just divide the range of value to some meaning full ranges
4. **formula**

   may be I am missing something but why are you mod-ing? As I see it you do not need the loop at all and also the ifs are obsolete so why to use `a+i*h` and not `a+=h`? it would improve performance and precision

   something like this:

   ```
   double sum,h;
   h = (b-a)/double(n-1);
   sum = 7.0*f(a); a+=h;
   sum+=32.0*f(a); a+=h;
   sum+=12.0*f(a); a+=h;
   sum+=32.0*f(a); a+=h;
   sum+= 7.0*f(a); a+=h;
   return 2.0*h*sum/45.0;
   // + the thing in the bullet 3 of coarse ...
   // now I see you had an error in your constants !!!
   ```

**[edit1] division implemented (not quadrupling)**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double f(double x)
    {
//  return x+0.2*x*x-0.001*x*x*x+2.0*cos(0.1*x)*tan(0.01*x*x)+25.0;
    return x+0.2*x*x-0.001*x*x*x;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double integrate_rect(double (*f)(double),double x0,double x1,int n)
    {
    int i;
    double s=0.0,x=x0,dx=(x1-x0)/double(n-1);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++,x+=dx) s+=f(x);
    return s*dx;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double integrate_Boole(double (*f)(double),double x0,double x1,int n)
    {
    n-=n%5; if (n<5) n=5;
    int i;
    double s=0.0,x=x0,dx=(x1-x0)/double(n-1);
    for (i=0;i<n;i+=5)
        {
        s+= 7.0*f(x); x+=dx;
        s+=32.0*f(x); x+=dx;
        s+=12.0*f(x); x+=dx;
        s+=32.0*f(x); x+=dx;
        s+= 7.0*f(x); x+=dx;
        }
    s*=(2.0*dx)/(45.0);
    return s*1.25; // this is the ratio to cover most cases
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main()
    {
    int n=100000;
    double x0=0.0,x1=+100.0,i0,i1;
    i0=integrate_rect (f,x0,x1,n); cout << i0 << endl;
    i1=integrate_Boole(f,x0,x1,n); cout << i1 << endl << i0/i1;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I use mostly rectangular rule because on **FPU** is the quickest and most precise way. The more advanced approaches are better on paper but on computer the added overhead and rounding is usually slower/less precise then the same accuracy with rectangular rule

Comment: Thank you for answering, I am modding becasue I want to break up [a,b] by n so let's say [1,0]. If N = 12 I would have 4 iterations of boole's rule on the smaller range. By having a smaller range The H value in my error term would be smaller (see error equation at the bottom of my post). I tried implementing your change to my code however, that raised the error term from approx 1.8645 * 10^-6 to 0.62831. I believe you cannot do the second 7*f because you have to have your start and ends overlap inside of the algorithm if that makes sense.

Comment: Please see the comment I posted to your answer in the comments section for a further explanation of the overlap.

Comment: @CodeMonkey 1. your n is constant n=5 so why it is in header and does it have the right value? 2. mine code represents the equation you have in OP (no loop there) so if you need a different one then you should include it into your post. 3. changing the coefficients in equation to correct the solution is not a good idea (if you have to derive the equation yourself then do it mathematically/geometrically not empirically!!! otherwise it will not work for all possible inputs)

Comment: @CodeMonkey also have you computed what the error should really be for your input?  hope you know the f(6)(c) means 6th derivation of f(x) by x ... what is your input function and interval ?

Comment: @CodeMonkey was curious and tested it against rectangular rule and the Boode's rule gives very strange results what are the constraints for input function/interval ?  this looks like some derivation/integration shortcut instead of geometric so it probably will not work for any given function

Comment: @CodeMonkey looks like the scale factor should be sum*=h/18 instead of sum*=2h/45 but hard to say if it is true for all functions ... updated code in answer

Comment: @spekte I was trying to be clever but it turns out I can't use mod because it messes up some of the counting so you were right. I replaced it with for loops and then I was getting errors inside of machine epsilon. Thank you for your answer, sorry for not getting back to you.