# Python: normalised cumulative distribution function from array of probability density function

Tags: python, arrays, probability, probability-density

For a continuous variable x and its probability density function p(x), I have a numpy array of x values `x` and a numpy array of corresponding p(x) values `p`. p(x) is not normalised though, i.e. in a plot of p(x) against x, the area under the graph is not 1. I want to calculate a corresponding array for values of the cumulative distribution function `cdf`. This is how I'm currently doing it, using the Trapezoidal rule to approximate an integral:

```
p_norm = p/np.trapz(p,x)
cdf = np.array([np.trapz(p_norm[:n],x[:n]) for n in range(len(p_norm))])
```

The results aren't entirely accurate; the final value of `cdf` is close to 1 but not exactly 1.

Is there any more accurate and simple way of normalising `p` and finding `cdf`? I thought there might be specific functions for this in some module; perhaps a statistics-oriented module with functions for related parameters (variance, confindence intervals etc) as well?

Comment: You can normalise `p` with `p / np.sum(p)` and then the CDF is `np.cumsum(p)`.

Comment: @Reti43 I think that works when x is a discrete variable, but not when its a continuous variable.

Comment: Do you have an expression for p, or do you have a lot of samples instead?

Comment: @Reti43 No, I don't have an expression for p(x), just an array of x values and an array of the corresponding p(x) values. The number of values in the arrays is typically large though.

Comment:  Try using some of the other methods I mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66593155/8474894). Also take a look at [`scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid.html) for evaluating the `cdf`.

Comment: A lot of samples != continuous. Your best bet is to integrate the area under your sampled curve and normalize with that. Your normalization factor will be only for the sampled area you have captured and will not be equal to the continuous one (if it has an expression). But assuming what you've left out from the tails is very small, it should be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

## Methods of Integration for Discrete Data-points

The variable `x` is only continuous if you have a continuous functional form for it. If you have a
few discrete values (which it will be if you were to make a numpy array of discrete values), then
the array is no longer continuous as it can not resolve points in between two successive discrete
values of `x`.

So, assuming that you, in effect have an array of discrete data-points for both `x` and `p`, here
are my suggestions.

### Get Acquainted With a Few Methods of Numerical Integration First

- [Newton-Cotes Formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-CotesFormulas.html)
  | **Code**: [**`scipy.integrate.newton_cotes`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.newton_cotes.html)

  This is a generic rule comprising of integration using `n`-points. If we denote the `n`-point formula as: `newton-cotes(n)`, then

  - [Trapezoidal Rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrapezoidalRule.html): `n = 2`
    | **Code**: [**`scipy.integrate.trapezoid`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.trapezoid.html)
  - [Simpson's Rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpsonsRule.html): `n = 3`
    | **Code**: [**`scipy.integrate.simpson`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simpson.html#scipy.integrate.simpson)
  - [Simpson's 3/8 Rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Simpsons38Rule.html): `n = 4`
  - [Boole's Rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoolesRule.html): `n = 5`
    | **Code**: See [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29701/booles-rule-in-python) for an idea.
- [Weddle's Rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeddlesRule.html)
- [Hardy's Rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HardysRule.html)

### 1. Integrate using [`scipy.integrate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html)

You can use any of the methods listed under *"Methods for Integrating Functions given fixed samples"*.

<kbd>**INSIGHT**</kbd>     **What is important here is**: in `trapezoidal rule` you
*`interpolate`* the space between the successive two points using a *`straight line`*. If you could
use a higher order polynomial (order ~ 2, 3, 4, etc.) then that could give you a better result for
integration. Simpson's rule uses 2nd-order polynomial [Simpson's Rule - *Wolfram MathWorld*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpsonsRule.html).

| [image: Simpson's Rule] | [image: gif] |
| --- | --- |
| **Simpson's Rule**: *Integrating area under a curve using quadratic polynomials* | An animation showing how Simpson's Rule is applied for integration |

<sup>**Source**: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule)</sup>

#### Methods for Integrating Functions given fixed samples

```
   trapezoid            -- "Use trapezoidal rule to compute integral."
   cumulative_trapezoid -- "Use trapezoidal rule to cumulatively compute integral."
   simps                -- "Use Simpson's rule to compute integral from samples."
   romb                 -- "Use Romberg Integration to compute integral from
                           (2**k + 1) evenly-spaced samples."
```

Also see this for a quick example: [Calculating the area under a curve given a set of coordinates, without knowing the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320262).

#### 2. Area Under the Curve (AUC) using `sklearn.metrics.auc`

Integration is in essence the area under a curve (AUC). Scikit-learn library provides an easy
alternative to calculating AUC. In practice this also uses the trapezoidal rule and so, I do
not see any reason why this should be any/much different from what you already have
using `numpy.trapz`.

- **Docs** - [`sklearn.metrics.auc`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html)
- Example: `auc = sklearn.metrics.auc(x, y)`

### 3. Consider using Other Methods

#### 3.1. Romberg Integration

```py
scipy.integrate.romb(y, dx=1.0, axis=- 1, show=False)
```

- Docs: [**`scipy.integrate.romb`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.romb.html#scipy.integrate.romb)
- What is Romberg's Method?

  - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romberg%27s_method)
  - Math behind Romberg Integration: [PDF](https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat460/fall09/lecture29.pdf)
  - YouTube Video: [Numerical Integration - Romberg Integration - example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWhqkZp0fxw)

### References

- [Boole's rule for N intervals (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521638/booles-rule-for-n-intervals-c)
- https://readthedocs.org/projects/mec-cs101-integrals/downloads/pdf/latest/

Comment: You go in detail discussing various integration methods and you miss out the key point that it should be normalized. Easy fix, but it really needs to be included.

Comment: @Reti43 Normalization is a part of defacto steps (anyone who understands probabilities would normalize either before or after integration -- both works; but I would prefer normalizing before). The OP asked for other methods -- so I shared those to let compare apples to apples. When you integrate something using various methods, the input must be kept the same for comparison. Besides, you had told the OP to normalize. Didn't see any point in mentioning it once again.